# Linux Mint Settings not accessible

Tags: linux-mint

When I try to access System Settings, clicking on the icon doesn't do anything.

I try from the CLI but nothing either.

I get this error from the CLI:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: 21:57:12.783: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  
Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 619, in <module>
window = MainWindow()
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 247, in __init__
    for module in modules:
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_backgrounds.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imtools
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py", line 623, in <module>
    if Image.VERSION == '1.1.7':
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

Has that already happened to you ? What did you do to fix it ?

Best,

Comment: What errors do you get in terminal? Please [edit] the question to add them.

Comment: here you go, using the cinnamon-settings command

Comment: It sounds like something got corrupted.  If you set up Timeshift, you can try rolling things back to an earlier point.  Otherwise, the most reliable fix might be to reinstall Mint.

Comment: Yes, I agree @fixer1234 . All the mentions to the error in the last line I could find point to some outdated "pillow" or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with PIL, it should be fixed soon, but in the meantime, you can fix it according to this [issue](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8495#issuecomment-480221648):

```
sudo vim /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py
```

Go to line 623, and change

```
if Image.VERSION == '1.1.7':
```

to

```
if getattr(Image, 'VERSION', None) == '1.1.7':
```

Than cinnamon-settings should start normally.

Comment: It really bothers me that all I have to do is update my software and a core function of the OS just disables completely. Don't they test?

Comment: Heyyyyy, it worked...

Comment: seriously, it worked.

Comment: This problem appeared for me today (more than one year and half later). I tried to update all packages thinking that they finally fixed but that did not work. I finally resigned to manually fix it but I wonder how this could have happened...